# PayPal NVP get shipping address on file

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I would like to verify that the postal code and country on file with PayPal match to the ones customer has provided on checkout process.

I'm using ADDROVERRIDE=1 to override PayPal shipping address with the one customer has selected on checkout.

the problem is GetExpressCheckout returns the overridden shipping address and not the one on file with PayPal.

Is there a way to first use minimal SetExpressCheckout call to get a token then call GetExpressCheckout to save the shipping address on file with PayPal and then redo full SetExpressCheckout?

I'm all hears to find better solution for my problem.

10x